# How should three images be tiled using ImageMagick montage?

Tags: image, imagemagick, tile, montage

I want to tile three images into a rectangle. Two of the images are to be on the left, on top of each other and set to the same width, and the remaining image is to be on the right.

```
---------
| 1 |   |
|---| 3 |
| 2 |   |
---------
```

I know that four images can be tiled using a command of the form following form:

```
montage 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png -mode Concatenate -tile 2x2 out.png

---------
| 1 | 2 |
|---|---|
| 3 | 4 |
---------
```

What would be the right command for tiling the three images?

For the specifics, the full rectangle is of the dimensions 1920 x 1080. Image 1 should be made to fit in 480 x 864 (maintaining its aspect ratio), image 2 is 480 x 216 and image 3 is 1440 x 1080.

```
-------------
| 1 |       |
|---|   3   |
| 2 |       |
-------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this should work for you:

```
convert \( 1.png -resize 480x864 \) 2.png -append 3.png +append result.png
```

[image]

Note that `-append` will append below, whereas `+append` will append to the right.

If you want to force `image2` to align with the *bottom* of `image3`, you can cause `image1` to fill the entire allotted space like this:

```
convert \( 1.png -resize 480x864 -extent 480x864 \) 2.png -append 3.png +append result.png
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I didn't realise `convert` could be used for this purpose. I have one small additional question if you have a moment: given that image 1 is not always of the right dimensions (hence my phrasing in the question to resize it), there can be some empty space below it. Do you know of a way to get image 2 to remain at the bottom left of the image, rather than rising to meet the bottom of the image above?

Comment: Not at my computer for a bit to test, but try setting the "extent" of image1 to 480x864 before appending image2.... `-extent 480x864` maybe preceded by `-gravity North`